# Fatal Error stops execution in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, exception, nullpointerexception, facebook-fql

I have following code in PHP

```
foreach($arr as $u){
    //code runs for users
    $u->fetchFriends();
}

function fetchFriends(){

$sparam = array('method' => 'fql.query', 
                'query' => $fql, 
                'callback' => '', 
                'access_token' => $fbtoken);

    try{
        $fqlResult = $facebook -> api($sparam);
        }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'There is issue with Token';
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the FB API throws an exception, then the process stops and next users in foreach loop doesn't get executed. I want that even if it throws an error, the foreach loop should run for all users.
Is that possible?

Comment: Does your real code define `fetchFriends` as a function with the `function` keyword?

Comment: Could you show us the fatal error? It should say something about the problem..

Comment: @EliasSoares Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190: Invalid OAuth access token. thrown in

Comment: @Paulpro the function works, just sometimes the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch those exceptions using a Facebook Api Exception catch block:

```
function fetchFriends(){

$sparam = array('method' => 'fql.query', 
                'query' => $fql, 
                'callback' => '', 
                'access_token' => $fbtoken);

    try {
        $fqlResult = $facebook -> api($sparam);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {//catch FB
        echo 'There is an issue with the Token';

    } catch(Exception $e) {//catch PHP
        echo $e->getMessage().' in '.$e->getFile().' on line '.$e->getLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @IarsAnders I do catch excpetion but they are not caught, btw why having 2 catch with 1 try?

Comment: In this case you can have different types of exceptions, requiring different catch blocks. You can have multiple `catch` blocks as well as a `finally` block. (Finally is similar to the `default` section of a `switch` statement - it executes after all the catches have been tried, but before resuming normal execution. Check it out [in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).